A question on couriers and liability in the United States?
Legally speaking, when a courier accepts a parcel with an agreement to deliver it from A to B, how much liability is accepted from the company from a legal standpoint?
Let's say the package gets blown up or tossed into a bonfire, and is thus not able to be delivered. How much liability would be owed to the shipper?
We can assume the following:

The package is being shipped from one state to another (ie, across state lines, but not internationally)
We're only interested in federal law (liability within state-law does not matter)
Only strict liability matters (so anything which adds extra damages from winning/losing a lawsuit shouldn't be considered)
The package had a known value which isn't in dispute.

How much is owed by the courier to the shipper in such a case under law?

Any courier would have an agreement with the shipper that covers this so you'd need to look at the contract between the shipper and the courier.  Virtually every courier would require the shipper to declare the value of the package and pay additional fees to cover the replacement cost if the package was lost if the declared value exceeded the courier's default limit.

@JustinCave we can say for this example, that there is no such agreement

It makes a difference why the package was lost or destroyed. Was it due to the courier's negligence, recklessness, etc? Did they destroy it deliberately? Was it the result of force majeure ("acts of God")?

You stipulated that there is an agreement to carry it from A to B. Are we to assume that a contract was formed, even if only an oral contract? Is there any indication from context or other evidence as to how the parties intended this situation to be handled, even if there was no explicit agreement?

@NateEldredge as above only strict liability matters, so no damages related to negligence are relevant here. we can assume a contract was formed, with the only agreement being the delivery of the parcel from A to B in exchange for shipping fees, and nothing in the contract stipulates what is to be done in any form if the parcel is rendered undeliverable.

I don't think "strict liability" means what you think it means.

@bdb484 https://legaldictionary.net/strict-liability/ "Liability incurred for causing damage or harm to life, limb, or property without the necessity of proving intent or negligence."

Yes, but the way you're using it, you seem to think it has additional implications regarding damages, etc. -- unless you're really just asking whether there is federal law imposing strict liability for losing a package, which it seems could have been asked much more simply.

@bdb484 by all means, edit the question if you think there is a clearer way to ask this.

That's the problem; it's not clear what you're asking, so it's hard to know whether I'd be clarifying or changing the question.

@bdb484 well it's clear enough that you have demonstrated here in the comments that you understand the premise, so unless there's an edit available, the text serves its purpose.

Are they a common carrier or a contract carrier?
A common carrier carries goods or people for the general public without discrimination for the "public convenience and necessity." Public airlines, railroads, bus lines, taxicab companies, phone companies, internet service providers (possibly), cruise ships, motor carriers (i.e., canal operating companies, trucking companies), and other freight companies generally operate as common carriers.
The US Postal Service, the New York subway, and Disneyland (roller coasters are a form of transport) are common carriers. FedEx and UPS are common carriers when carrying goods on published routes at published rates. So are American Airlines and AmTrak.
A contract carrier carries goods or people subject to specifically negotiated contracts. Their services are not offered to the general public and they can refuse carriage.
FedEx and UPS are contract carriers when carrying goods on a negotiated basis that they cannot or will not carry on their scheduled routes. So is American Airlines when they operate a charter flight.
There are also private carriers who only transport their own goods and personal and don’t provide services to third-parties. Walmart and the US military are private carriers.
Liability for a common carrier

In common law jurisdictions as well as under international law, a common carrier is absolutely liable for goods carried by it, with four exceptions:


An act of nature
An act of the public enemies
Fault or fraud by the shipper
An inherent defect in the goods

In addition, for goods carried by ship, the carrier is not liable for a fire on board the ship or an error in navigation by the ship’s master.
Local or international laws may limit a common carriers liability to a maximum amount, which may vary depending on the type of goods. For example, compensation for international air transport is limited by the Montreal Convention.
A common carrier may, but is not required, to offer insurance to cover goods over the limits.
Liability for contract carriers
Whatever it says in the contract.

So strictly speaking, if nothing is mentioned in a contract carrier's contract, they're liable for just that, nothing?

Is liability really limited to the contents of the contact? I'd expect this situation to be governed by the common law of bailments.

@tuskiomi there’s never nothing mentioned in a contract carrier’s contract - these are typically for tens of thousands, perhaps millions of dollars. You don’t do that on a handshake.

@tuskiomi If there's nothing mentioned about liability in a contract carrier's contract you need to fire your lawyer, since that feels like one of the most basic things to put in a contract to transport goods. Or, if you for some weird reason negotiated that contract yourself, get a lawyer next time.

so what I'm hearing is that we don't know. Is that a valid conclusion?

@tuskiomi on the facts stated, we don’t have enough information

@DaleM barring retroactively changing the contract, is there anything that could be added for clarity?
